# Can't access twitteR

Tags: r, twitter, oauth, devtools, httr

I have been reading up on the past posts and this still isn't working for me. I want to use the twitteR package but it won't let me read the the token keys and secrets.

Here is the code which can be reproducible and I was hoping someone can give me a detailed answer on what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

```
library(twitteR)
library(httr)
cKey1 <- "consumer key"
cSecret1 <- "consumer secret"
aKey1<- "access key"
aSecret1 <- "access secret" 

setup_twitter_oauth(cKey1, cSecret1, aKey1, aSecret1)

[1] "Using direct authentication"
Use a local file to cache OAuth access credentials between R sessions?
1: Yes
2: No

Selection: 1

Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'
```

So some of the recent posts have mentioned to try the following:

Download a recent version of httr (0.0.6) but that doesn't work because twitteR doesn't support that.

Another one is installing:

```
devtools::install_github("jrowen/twitteR", ref = "oauth_httr_1_0")
```

This doesn't work either because the same error happens.

If someone has found an answer to this problem I would greatly appreciate their input, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
devtools::install_github("geoffjentry/twitteR")
```

This finally worked